# SQL Reporting Services custom security extension approach to use for multiple applications

Tags: c#, reporting-services, session-cookies

I have created a custom security extension describes here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155029.aspx.

We have a application that store username, groups, etc.
The custom security extension fetch data from application. All works fine so far.

Now there is the new challenge:
I want to have multiple applications, that use the same report server.
My approach is, that my custom security extension connects different databases for authentication and authorization. I implemented this so far and in theorey this works fine.

I run in to one problem that make me headaches.
I thought, simple identify each connection with a custom table where I store the session (request cookie from my application, works in `UILogon.aspx.cs` and `Logon.aspx.cs`) and the domain (via `Request.Url.Host` in the same pages).
I store those data in a custom created table in ReportServer database and in all other methods I get the cookie session informationen to retrieve the info which domain it is to choose to correct database.

My problem: I loose the cookie information to identify the session.
I tried made a Singelton instance class to store this for each instance, but this is not "application" wide. So I thought, well somehow the SQL reporting services must hold the info about the session (probably in an own SSRS session cookie). If this is accessable I can store domain and ssrs session cookie to identify it.

So, how I can read / get the ssrs session cookie information in the methods.
E.g.

```
public bool CheckAccess(
    string userName,
    IntPtr userToken,
    byte[] secDesc,
    FolderOperation requiredOperation)
{
// here I need to know in which SSRS session I am
}
```

Anyone know how to get this OR how to identify unique a session so I can map the session to additional information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution....

I send my own Session Cookie to the server to identify where I am !

```
        <PassThroughCookies>
          <PassThroughCookie>_cookie_session</PassThroughCookie>
        </PassThroughCookies>
```

Then I have `var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["_cookie_session"];` always my cookie and can get the ID to identify the instance.

Comment: May I know how did you send the session cookie and from where?
I use 2017 and I have a similar situation but since I'm using the restful API the "HttpContext.Current" always null. So not sure if this approach would work at all but I would like to give it a go. thanks

Comment: @et3rnal Hi, I am not 100% sure what you mean, but what I can tell you that this also works on SSRS 2017. We just modified our project so everything works fine with 2016 and 2017. In `public class Authorization : IAuthorizationExtension` you will have access to `var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["_your_cookie"];` if you send requests via /reportserver url.

Comment: In `Logon.aspx.cs` you can access it using `Request.Cookies` also.

Comment: I can't use /ReportServer to consume APIs!, are you using the restful APIs v2.0? as HttpContext.Current is null always inside Authorization! Also, may I know what is your configuration for sessionState ? I have tried login through Login.aspx.cs and it still the same HttpContext.Current is null, however, I can access HttpContext inside AuthenticationExtension : IAuthenticationExtension2, IExtension class as part of the Logon.aspx page request?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you try todo, but I use custom security extension from here https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services (and older ones). There I do implement my own single sign on login to user `/ReportServer` and `/reports` SSRS features. `/ReportServer` url ist the web service itself, so the custom security extension uses this.

Comment: I've done SSO as well, but using the new one since this is what the docs say to use for 2017? but I'm implementing the reports within my application so I'm using the Restful APIs which you aren't using? this is why you don't have the issue. the APIs endpoint in/reports and anything going through it doesn't have HttpContext.Current !!